# Sequence of data in 3D, joining the points

Tags: plotting

Let me just first say I am not actually trying to find a function for these set of data. All I am doing is joining the points to make a line.

Basically let's say I have some data, which I cleverly will call/name them as 'data' in Mathematica.

```
data:= {{1,0,0},{2,4,7},{2,6,7},{0,0,23}}
```

Now plotting them. (FYI, these data points are randomlly chosen)

```
ListPointPlot3D[data]
```

I should get a plot, but of course they are all disconnected. What I want to do is to join them. Unfortunately `'Joined -> True'` does not exists in `ListPointPlot3D`, so I do not know how to join them

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

At the moment, I have a recursion. I will just show you the table

For instance

```
Table[x[n, t], {n, 1, 10}]
```

prints out a list of 10 data points in 3D. It will not work with `Graphics3D`

**EDIT**

I will write out exactly what I have

> x[1, t_] := {0,0,0};
>
> A[t_] := {{1, -t, 1}, {t, 2, 0}, {0, 0,t}}
>
> B[t_] := Inverse[A[t]];
>
> x[n_Integer, t_] /; n > 0 := B[t].x[n - 1, t];
>
> Table[x[n, t], {n, 1, 10}]

I want to plot the points and join them in a curve. If possilbe I would even like to manipulate the plot. The range for $t \in [0,1]$

Everything updated

Comment: You could just use `Graphics3D[Line[data]]`...

Comment: What do you mean by "it will not work"?

Comment: It gives me an error. I will write out the code.

Comment: Your definition for A[t_] is circular, it can't work ... and you have two defs for the same thing (A[t_])

Comment: I made a typo, one sec

Answer (score 4):

```
t := RandomReal[]
x[n_, t_] := Sin@t
data = Table[{n, #, x[n, #]} &[t], {n, 1, 10}];

Graphics3D[{Line@data, PointSize[Large], Point@data}, 
           PlotRange -> ({Min@# - 1, Max@# + 1} & /@ Transpose@data), Axes -> True]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Also something like this shall do

```
f = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ Transpose@data;
Show[{ParametricPlot3D[Through[f[t]], {t, 1, Length@data}], 
      Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point@data}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: OKay it connects them, but now I lose my points. I want to see the dots as well. You see what I mean?

Comment: @jak See edit, please

Comment: There is also one other problem, which I will edit in OP.

Comment: see edit 10 chat

Answer (score 3):

Of course the `Graphics3D` approach in belisarius' answer is very general and should always work. But maybe you want to stick with `ListPointPlot3D` for some reason. Then you could use `Show` to combine the isolated points with a plot of the linear `Interpolation` between the points:

```
data = {{1, 0, 0}, {2, 4, 7}, {2, 6, 7}, {0, 0, 23}}

(* ==> {{1, 0, 0}, {2, 4, 7}, {2, 6, 7}, {0, 0, 23}} *)

iData = 
  Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[Length[#]], #} &@data], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[data], ParametricPlot3D[iData[t], {t, 1, 4}]
 ]
```

[image: Show plots]

It's worth mentioning here that `Show` always uses the options of the plot that comes first in the list, unless you specify additional options to `Show` (such as `BoxRatios`, if desired). You can also control the style of the points and curve separately using the usual options.

Comment: I always doubt when formatting a 3D list for feeding it into `Interpolation`. Sometimes I do like you did, and sometimes as in my answer here. Do you have any thoughts about what is the better way?

Comment: I would have used your method, that's why I upvoted it... My answer was just motivated by the apparent "other problem" of the OP, which I don't understand yet.

Comment: As I understand it, he has `{f1, f2, f3, ...}` instead of `{{x1,y1,f1} , {x2,y2,f2}, ...}`

Comment: @belisarius For what it's worth I would write: `Interpolation @ MapIndexed[{#2, #} &, data]`

Comment: See edit 10 char