# Plotting ListLinePlots together creating a 3D view

Tags: plotting

I have a `*.xlsx` file containing four columns, each pair representing an `x` and `y` value,  so (from left to right): `x_sample1`, `y_sample1`, `x_sample2`, `y_sample2`.

What I wanted to do, is put them in a `ListLinePlot` (or something similar) next to each other in a 3-D view. I managed to get what I wanted using `ListPointPlot`, but a continuous line for each sample would look better for my purposes. `ListPointPlot` (to my knowledge) only let me use `Filling` to simulate a more continuous, solid look - but that doesn't really cut it.
Attached below is a picture of what I did so far and how the general look of it should be.
[image]

I used a (rather ugly) workaround to get this to work: for each plot I added an artificial x value named "row" in integer values from 1-14 and these were followed by the original plot data corresponding to y and z data for this plot.

The code I used is:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{exceldaten[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], exceldaten[[All, {4, 5, 6}]], 
          exceldaten[[All, {7, 8, 9}]], exceldaten[[All, {10, 11, 12}]],
          exceldaten[[All, {13, 14, 15}]], exceldaten[[All, {16, 17, 18}]], 
          exceldaten[[All, {19, 20, 21}]], exceldaten[[All, {22, 23, 24}]], 
          exceldaten[[All, {25, 26, 27}]], exceldaten[[All, {28, 29, 30}]], 
          exceldaten[[All, {31, 32, 33}]], exceldaten[[All, {34, 35, 36}]], 
          exceldaten[[All, {37, 38, 39}]], exceldaten[[All, {40, 41, 42}]]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0.5, 14.5}, {0.0002, 0.0006}, {0, 50000}}, 
     Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Automatic, Axes -> {False, True,True}, 
     AxesLabel -> {None, "mobility (corresponding unit)", "cps"}, 
     Ticks -> {header[[3 ;; 42 ;; 3]], Automatic, Automatic}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], PlotLegends -> header[[3 ;; 42 ;; 3]]]
```

Comment: Might be related: [22878](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22878/sequence-of-data-in-3d-joining-the-points)

Answer (score 7):

You can use Polygon to get this effect. If you use `ListPointPlot3D` as well, you have easy access to the axes.

```
a = Table[{j, i, i*Exp[-(j - 6)^2/(4)]}, {i, 1, 12}, {j, 1, 10}];
c = ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range[1, Length@a];
Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[a, PlotStyle -> c],
 Graphics3D[{#1, Polygon[#2]}] & @@@ Transpose@{c, a}
 ]
```

Which gives

[image]

Or you can use EdgeForm and FaceForm to get lines

```
Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[a, PlotStyle -> c],
 Graphics3D[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[#1], Polygon[#2]}] & @@@ 
  Transpose@{c, a}
 ]
```

[image]

Edit: Obviously, you could use Line as well, which gets rid of the lines on the x-y plane.

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[a, PlotStyle -> c], 
 Graphics3D[{#1, Line[#2]}] & @@@ Transpose@{c, a}]
```

[image]