# Line plot with 3DListPointPlot

Tags: plotting

I have been trying make a plot that I have with ListPointPlot3D into a line plot instead of a point plot. I wish there was something called ListLinePlot3D. I've seen examples with,

```
/.Point-> Line
```

,after the code but it just returns a blank graph for me. What is going on? Here is a picture of the graph thus far. I've been able to use this "trick" for other plots just fine but I'm wondering if it has to do with the fact that in this context I have a "4d" plot (3D + color).

[image: This is a 3D + color plot that I want connected with a line instead of points]

```
   normdSi = 
  Table[(p - Min[Sidata1[[All, 2]]])/(Max[Sidata1[[All, 2]]] - 
      Min[Sidata1[[All, 2]]]), {p, Sidata1[[All, 2]]}];
colorsSi = Table[ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][d], {d, normdSi}];
Si4dplot = 
 ListPointPlot3D[{#[[3 ;; 5]]} & /@ Sidata1, PlotStyle -> colorsSi, 
  AxesLabel -> {"q", "s2", "\[Alpha]"}, ImageSize -> Full, 
  LabelStyle -> {18}, PlotLabel -> Style["Si", 24]]/.Point->Line
```

Here is my data. It has 5 columns with 201 rows.

```
{{0, 0.00586554, 1.85613, 4.76551*10^-28, 5.26926}, {1, 0.00586038, 
  1.85857, 0.00496208, 5.26553}, {2, 0.00583292, 1.86694, 0.00737286, 
  5.28264}, {3, 0.00578611, 1.88105, 0.00995626, 5.31438}, {4, 
  0.00572788, 1.90041, 0.0195179, 5.34518}, {5, 0.0056491, 1.92576, 
  0.026371, 5.3971}, {6, 0.00555664, 1.95654, 0.0357567, 5.4579}, {7, 
  0.005454, 1.99256, 0.0488175, 5.52469}, {8, 0.00533414, 2.03443, 
  0.0587529, 5.61315}, {9, 0.00520924, 2.08121, 0.0728039, 
  5.70511}, {10, 0.00507624, 2.13333, 0.0868532, 5.80991}, {11, 
  0.00493048, 2.19114, 0.0969574, 5.937}, {12, 0.00479085, 2.25265, 
  0.111276, 6.06199}, {13, 0.00464483, 2.31891, 0.12169, 
  6.20612}, {14, 0.00449348, 2.3895, 0.12767, 6.36945}, {15, 
  0.00435635, 2.46022, 0.134399, 6.52873}, {16, 0.00421573, 2.53408, 
  0.13467, 6.70861}, {17, 0.00408066, 2.60798, 0.130038, 
  6.89764}, {18, 0.003962, 2.67731, 0.122165, 7.08088}, {19, 
  0.0038446, 2.74659, 0.107359, 7.27855}, {20, 0.0037445, 2.80767, 
  0.0891022, 7.46372}, {21, 0.00366125, 2.85969, 0.0685708, 
  7.63264}, {22, 0.00358362, 2.90781, 0.0439095, 7.80201}, {23, 
  0.00353606, 2.93743, 0.0254055, 7.91445}, {24, 0.00350441, 2.9569, 
  0.0112019, 7.99332}, {25, 0.00348267, 2.96992, 4.2709*10^-28, 
  8.05004}, {26, 0.00350619, 2.95655, 0.0140871, 7.98594}, {27, 
  0.00354397, 2.9359, 0.0380519, 7.88204}, {28, 0.0036054, 2.90368, 
  0.077481, 7.71557}, {29, 0.00371579, 2.84915, 0.145356, 
  7.43302}, {30, 0.00384706, 2.78696, 0.22453, 7.10949}, {31, 
  0.00402225, 2.70695, 0.319264, 6.71886}, {32, 0.00425262, 2.60492, 
  0.42526, 6.26836}, {33, 0.00451347, 2.4927, 0.533519, 5.80028}, {34,
   0.00484984, 2.35888, 0.635259, 5.31261}, {35, 0.0052487, 2.21331, 
  0.726175, 4.82797}, {36, 0.00569123, 2.06324, 0.807586, 
  4.35526}, {37, 0.00625698, 1.90488, 0.858761, 3.92207}, {38, 
  0.00689091, 1.74683, 0.894649, 3.51698}, {39, 0.00759815, 1.59081, 
  0.915479, 3.14207}, {40, 0.00847396, 1.44051, 0.907596, 
  2.82513}, {41, 0.00943069, 1.29475, 0.890287, 2.53427}, {42, 
  0.0105185, 1.15519, 0.860229, 2.27889}, {43, 0.0117991, 1.02388, 
  0.81632, 2.06547}, {44, 0.0131859, 0.897942, 0.767916, 
  1.87227}, {45, 0.0147797, 0.780792, 0.713042, 1.70999}, {46, 
  0.0165753, 0.670983, 0.65441, 1.57258}, {47, 0.0184995, 0.565447, 
  0.594737, 1.44957}, {48, 0.0207039, 0.467657, 0.533712, 
  1.35086}, {49, 0.0230828, 0.374668, 0.47279, 1.26641}, {50, 
  0.025591, 0.285255, 0.412327, 1.1928}, {51, 0.0283735, 0.201725, 
  0.353629, 1.13931}, {52, 0.0312372, 0.119185, 0.295722, 
  1.09523}, {53, 0.0341712, 0.0377658, 0.238978, 1.06272}, {54, 
  0.0370919, -0.0411159, 0.184837, 1.04753}, {55, 0.03991, -0.118284, 
  0.132156, 1.04359}, {56, 0.0424219, -0.189196, 0.0842067, 
  1.05721}, {57, 0.0443678, -0.245829, 0.0451427, 1.09405}, {58, 
  0.0458307, -0.287877, 0.0134487, 1.15053}, {59, 
  0.0461722, -0.273939, 0.00724523, 1.25192}, {60, 0.04547, -0.189799,
   0.029489, 1.40789}, {61, 0.0439536, -0.040825, 0.0760268, 
  1.61787}, {62, 0.0410509, 0.287135, 0.188407, 1.98092}, {63, 
  0.0374884, 0.737128, 0.339519, 2.48104}, {64, 0.0334165, 1.32035, 
  0.529929, 3.15253}, {65, 0.0292259, 2.16715, 0.792678, 
  4.24807}, {66, 0.0249774, 3.20952, 1.09423, 5.70677}, {67, 
  0.0209618, 4.54328, 1.4547, 7.76466}, {68, 0.0175535, 6.37734, 
  1.90226, 10.9599}, {69, 0.0142979, 8.71509, 2.3962, 15.3082}, {70, 
  0.0116484, 11.9196, 2.96614, 21.8363}, {71, 0.00952234, 16.4455, 
  3.46263, 31.8198}, {72, 0.00756156, 22.4422, 3.69173, 45.7099}, {73,
   0.00637376, 29.2974, 3.10612, 62.8753}, {74, 0.00557852, 35.9338, 
  1.7877, 80.5131}, {75, 0.0050232, 41.7985, 8.59236*10^-27, 
  96.93}, {76, 0.00564134, 35.4285, 2.17511, 78.8748}, {77, 
  0.00664996, 27.396, 4.4568, 56.9122}, {78, 0.00830127, 18.7827, 
  5.93387, 34.9235}, {79, 0.0112518, 12.1619, 5.34133, 20.6996}, {80, 
  0.0147477, 7.27342, 4.38667, 11.0649}, {81, 0.0192714, 4.31069, 
  3.28923, 6.07815}, {82, 0.0249166, 2.64861, 2.36017, 3.78892}, {83, 
  0.0310646, 1.44104, 1.61259, 2.25868}, {84, 0.038089, 0.763281, 
  1.11354, 1.51843}, {85, 0.0455155, 0.323334, 0.756884, 
  1.08172}, {86, 0.0530392, -0.00833097, 0.480004, 0.764547}, {87, 
  0.0602388, -0.191606, 0.314908, 0.599}, {88, 0.0669456, -0.322307, 
  0.19112, 0.476188}, {89, 0.0729913, -0.407595, 0.101166, 
  0.385506}, {90, 0.0773187, -0.422702, 0.0563086, 0.338125}, {91, 
  0.0808823, -0.415833, 0.0252911, 0.301559}, {92, 
  0.0833385, -0.387366, 0.00888385, 0.276938}, {93, 
  0.0845245, -0.347873, 0.00355736, 0.262038}, {94, 
  0.085323, -0.310296, 0.000716217, 0.249179}, {95, 
  0.0854916, -0.278922, 0.00021299, 0.239806}, {96, 
  0.0853257, -0.253975, 0.000358958, 0.232963}, {97, 
  0.0851545, -0.232974, 0.000267074, 0.227071}, {98, 
  0.0848481, -0.218693, 0.000354803, 0.223956}, {99, 
  0.084646, -0.209427, 0.000303089, 0.222006}, {100, 
  0.0846189, -0.204535, 3.2539*10^-31, 0.220639}, {101, 
  0.084646, -0.209427, 0.000303089, 0.222006}, {102, 
  0.0848481, -0.218693, 0.000354803, 0.223956}, {103, 
  0.0851545, -0.232974, 0.000267074, 0.227071}, {104, 
  0.0853257, -0.253975, 0.000358958, 0.232963}, {105, 
  0.0854916, -0.278922, 0.00021299, 0.239806}, {106, 
  0.085323, -0.310296, 0.000716217, 0.249179}, {107, 
  0.0845245, -0.347873, 0.00355736, 0.262038}, {108, 
  0.0833385, -0.387366, 0.00888385, 0.276938}, {109, 
  0.0808823, -0.415833, 0.0252911, 0.301559}, {110, 
  0.0773187, -0.422702, 0.0563086, 0.338125}, {111, 
  0.0729913, -0.407595, 0.101166, 0.385506}, {112, 
  0.0669456, -0.322307, 0.19112, 0.476188}, {113, 
  0.0602388, -0.191606, 0.314908, 0.599}, {114, 
  0.0530392, -0.00833097, 0.480004, 0.764547}, {115, 0.0455155, 
  0.323334, 0.756884, 1.08172}, {116, 0.038089, 0.763281, 1.11354, 
  1.51843}, {117, 0.0310646, 1.44104, 1.61259, 2.25868}, {118, 
  0.0249166, 2.64861, 2.36017, 3.78892}, {119, 0.0192714, 4.31069, 
  3.28923, 6.07815}, {120, 0.0147477, 7.27342, 4.38667, 
  11.0649}, {121, 0.0112518, 12.1619, 5.34133, 20.6996}, {122, 
  0.00830127, 18.7827, 5.93387, 34.9235}, {123, 0.00664996, 27.396, 
  4.4568, 56.9122}, {124, 0.00564134, 35.4285, 2.17511, 
  78.8748}, {125, 0.0050232, 41.7985, 5.2584*10^-27, 96.93}, {126, 
  0.00557852, 35.9338, 1.7877, 80.5131}, {127, 0.00637376, 29.2974, 
  3.10612, 62.8753}, {128, 0.00756156, 22.4422, 3.69173, 
  45.7099}, {129, 0.00952234, 16.4455, 3.46263, 31.8198}, {130, 
  0.0116484, 11.9196, 2.96614, 21.8363}, {131, 0.0142979, 8.71509, 
  2.3962, 15.3082}, {132, 0.0175535, 6.37734, 1.90226, 10.9599}, {133,
   0.0209618, 4.54328, 1.4547, 7.76466}, {134, 0.0249774, 3.20952, 
  1.09423, 5.70677}, {135, 0.0292259, 2.16715, 0.792678, 
  4.24807}, {136, 0.0334165, 1.32035, 0.529929, 3.15253}, {137, 
  0.0374884, 0.737128, 0.339519, 2.48104}, {138, 0.0410509, 0.287135, 
  0.188407, 1.98092}, {139, 0.0439536, -0.040825, 0.0760268, 
  1.61787}, {140, 0.04547, -0.189799, 0.029489, 1.40789}, {141, 
  0.0461722, -0.273939, 0.00724523, 1.25192}, {142, 
  0.0458307, -0.287877, 0.0134487, 1.15053}, {143, 
  0.0443678, -0.245829, 0.0451427, 1.09405}, {144, 
  0.0424219, -0.189196, 0.0842067, 1.05721}, {145, 0.03991, -0.118284,
   0.132156, 1.04359}, {146, 0.0370919, -0.0411159, 0.184837, 
  1.04753}, {147, 0.0341712, 0.0377658, 0.238978, 1.06272}, {148, 
  0.0312372, 0.119185, 0.295722, 1.09523}, {149, 0.0283735, 0.201725, 
  0.353629, 1.13931}, {150, 0.025591, 0.285255, 0.412327, 
  1.1928}, {151, 0.0230828, 0.374668, 0.47279, 1.26641}, {152, 
  0.0207039, 0.467657, 0.533712, 1.35086}, {153, 0.0184995, 0.565447, 
  0.594737, 1.44957}, {154, 0.0165753, 0.670983, 0.65441, 
  1.57258}, {155, 0.0147797, 0.780792, 0.713042, 1.70999}, {156, 
  0.0131859, 0.897942, 0.767916, 1.87227}, {157, 0.0117991, 1.02388, 
  0.81632, 2.06547}, {158, 0.0105185, 1.15519, 0.860229, 
  2.27889}, {159, 0.00943069, 1.29475, 0.890287, 2.53427}, {160, 
  0.00847396, 1.44051, 0.907596, 2.82513}, {161, 0.00759815, 1.59081, 
  0.915479, 3.14207}, {162, 0.00689091, 1.74683, 0.894649, 
  3.51698}, {163, 0.00625698, 1.90488, 0.858761, 3.92207}, {164, 
  0.00569123, 2.06324, 0.807586, 4.35526}, {165, 0.0052487, 2.21331, 
  0.726175, 4.82797}, {166, 0.00484984, 2.35888, 0.635259, 
  5.31261}, {167, 0.00451347, 2.4927, 0.533519, 5.80028}, {168, 
  0.00425262, 2.60492, 0.42526, 6.26836}, {169, 0.00402225, 2.70695, 
  0.319264, 6.71886}, {170, 0.00384706, 2.78696, 0.22453, 
  7.10949}, {171, 0.00371579, 2.84915, 0.145356, 7.43302}, {172, 
  0.0036054, 2.90368, 0.077481, 7.71557}, {173, 0.00354397, 2.9359, 
  0.0380519, 7.88204}, {174, 0.00350619, 2.95655, 0.0140871, 
  7.98594}, {175, 0.00348267, 2.96992, 4.34023*10^-27, 8.05004}, {176,
   0.00350441, 2.9569, 0.0112019, 7.99332}, {177, 0.00353606, 2.93743,
   0.0254055, 7.91445}, {178, 0.00358362, 2.90781, 0.0439095, 
  7.80201}, {179, 0.00366125, 2.85969, 0.0685708, 7.63264}, {180, 
  0.0037445, 2.80767, 0.0891022, 7.46372}, {181, 0.0038446, 2.74659, 
  0.107359, 7.27855}, {182, 0.003962, 2.67731, 0.122165, 
  7.08088}, {183, 0.00408066, 2.60798, 0.130038, 6.89764}, {184, 
  0.00421573, 2.53408, 0.13467, 6.70861}, {185, 0.00435635, 2.46022, 
  0.134399, 6.52873}, {186, 0.00449348, 2.3895, 0.12767, 
  6.36945}, {187, 0.00464483, 2.31891, 0.12169, 6.20612}, {188, 
  0.00479085, 2.25265, 0.111276, 6.06199}, {189, 0.00493048, 2.19114, 
  0.0969574, 5.937}, {190, 0.00507624, 2.13333, 0.0868532, 
  5.80991}, {191, 0.00520924, 2.08121, 0.0728039, 5.70511}, {192, 
  0.00533414, 2.03443, 0.0587529, 5.61315}, {193, 0.005454, 1.99256, 
  0.0488175, 5.52469}, {194, 0.00555664, 1.95654, 0.0357567, 
  5.4579}, {195, 0.0056491, 1.92576, 0.026371, 5.3971}, {196, 
  0.00572788, 1.90041, 0.0195179, 5.34518}, {197, 0.00578611, 1.88105,
   0.00995626, 5.31438}, {198, 0.00583292, 1.86694, 0.00737286, 
  5.28264}, {199, 0.00586038, 1.85857, 0.00496208, 5.26553}, {200, 
  0.00586554, 1.85613, 4.76551*10^-28, 5.26926}}
```

**EDIT**

I tried using your response and this is what I have written in my code. But this is the plot that I am getting. The yellowish points aren't there?

[image]

```
normdSi = 
  Table[(p - Min[Sidata1[[All, 2]]])/(Max[Sidata1[[All, 2]]] - 
      Min[Sidata1[[All, 2]]]), {p, Sidata1[[All, 2]]}];
colorsSi = Table[ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][d], {d, normdSi}];
lpp3d1 = ListPointPlot3D[{#[[3 ;; 5]]} & /@ Sidata1, 
   PlotStyle -> colorsSi, AxesLabel -> {"q", "s2", "\[Alpha]"}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {18}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Si", 24], ViewPoint -> {-3, -2, 1}];
lpp3d1 /. 
 points : {{Directive[_, _], Point[_]} ..} :> {Thick, 
   Line[points[[All, 2, 1, 1]], VertexColors -> points[[All, 1, 2]]]}
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. However, the outcome isn't quite what I wanted visually, I would like to keep the 3d + color plot along with all of my axes labels and such. Ideally, I want it to look identical to the picture I included with this question but just that the points are connected with lines.

Comment: Have you tried the `Interpolation` and `ParametricPlot3D` solution from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22881/58370).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I am not quite sure how to use either of those on my case? Could you show me how with my data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lpp3d1 = ListPointPlot3D[{#[[3 ;; 5]]} & /@ Sidata1, 
   PlotStyle -> colorsSi, AxesLabel -> {"q", "s2", "α"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   LabelStyle -> {18},  PlotLabel -> Style["Si", 24], ViewPoint -> {-3, -2, 1}];
```

#### 1.

Remove braces from `{#[[3 ;; 5]]} &` in the first argument of `ListPointPlot3D` and use replacement rule `Point -> Line`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[#[[3 ;; 5]] & /@ Sidata1, PlotStyle -> colorsSi, 
   AxesLabel -> {"q", "s2", "\[Alpha]"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   LabelStyle -> {18}, PlotLabel -> Style["Si", 24], 
   ViewPoint -> {-3, -2, 1}] /. Point -> Line
```

[image]

#### 2.

If you want the line retain colors associated with points, use  a more elaborate replacement rule:

```
lpp3d1 /. points : {{Directive[_, _], Point[_]} ..} :> 
   {Thick, Line[points[[All, 2, 1, 1]], VertexColors -> points[[All, 1, 2]]]}
```

[image]

If you want to show both the points and the lines, use

```
lpp3d1 /. points : {{Directive[_, _], Point[_]} ..} :> 
   {points, Thick, Line[points[[All, 2, 1, 1]], VertexColors -> points[[All, 1, 2]]]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to remove the points so that it is just a smooth line?

Comment: @btilson, please try the updated versions.

Comment: thank you! however, now I am having a problem with it not showing the all the points? See my edit in my question to see what I get when I plugged your solution into mathematica.

Comment: Just kidding! It is there just had to zoom in! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: how could I use the replacement rule shown above for the line retaining the colors associated to points in 2D? I am trying to plot columns 3 and 4. Here is my code so far `qs2 = ListPlot[{#[[{3, 4}]]} & /@ Sidata1, PlotStyle -> colorsSi, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 7}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  LabelStyle -> {18, Black}, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend["BlueGreenYellow"], 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Si", 24]]
qs2 /. points : {{Directive[_, _], Point[_]} ..} :> {Thick, 
   Line[points[[All, 2, 1, 1]], VertexColors -> points[[All, 1, 2]]]}`

Answer (score 2):

> I am not quite sure how to use either of those on my case? Could you
>   show me how with my data?

```
iData = Interpolation@MapIndexed[{#2, #} &, Sidata1[[All, 3 ;; 5]]];

Si4dplot = ListPointPlot3D[{#[[3 ;; 5]]} & /@ Sidata1,
   PlotStyle -> colorsSi,
   AxesLabel -> {"q", "s2", "\[Alpha]"},
   LabelStyle -> {18},
   PlotLabel -> Style["Si", 24],
   ViewPoint -> {-3, -2, 1}];

Show[Si4dplot, ParametricPlot3D[iData[t], {t, 1, Length@Sidata1}]]
```

[image]